# GROUP and ORDER Mysql get diffrent data in column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

this is all data from current table

```
SELECT
  id,harga,kode_tahun_ajaran
FROM
  tblharga
+----+---------+-------------------+
| id | harga   | kode_tahun_ajaran |
+----+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |  400000 | THN2018/2019      |
|  2 |   50000 | THN2018/2019      |
|  3 | 1000000 | THN2018/2019      |
|  4 |  900000 | THN2018/2019      |
|  5 |  500000 | THN2017/2018      |
|  6 |  600000 | THN2018/2019      |
+----+---------+-------------------+
```

and i run this code to get the last ***harga*** with grouping the ***kode_tahun_ajaran***

```
  SELECT
    id,harga,kode_tahun_ajaran
  FROM
    tblharga
  GROUP BY
    kode_tahun_ajaran
  ORDER BY id DESC
+----+--------+-------------------+
| id | harga  | kode_tahun_ajaran |
+----+--------+-------------------+
|  5 | 500000 | THN2017/2018      |
|  1 | 400000 | THN2018/2019      |
+----+--------+-------------------+
```

the ***harga*** column should take the last data which is 600000 because of the ***order by*** code.

how can I retrieve the latest data by grouping it another way?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put on the strict_mode in MySQL then you will see that your query is actually broken. You need to aggregate columns that you don't group. Otherwise the output is random as in your case.

Comment: so how to avoid the random data? @juergend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT
    id,harga,kode_tahun_ajaran
  FROM
    tblharga where id in (select max(id) from tblharga group by kode_tahun_ajaran)
```

Comment: How about `where id in (select max(id) from tblharga group by kode_tahun_ajaran)`  ?

Comment: this query only output 1 data where there are 2 diffrent data in **_kode_tahun_ajaran_** column's

Comment: @ivgadil, have you checked my updated answer - it should return 2 data for kode_tahun_ajaran

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,S.kode_tahun_ajaran,harga
from tblharga S inner join
( select kode_tahun_ajaran,max(id) maxid from tblharga group by kode_tahun_ajaran) T
where T.kode_tahun_ajaran=S.kode_tahun_ajaran and maxid=id;
```

Comment: i'm sorry @oguzismail but i think it is one of the possible answers  there could be better ones but if you run the query it should run (except for some typos...). I tested with another table

Comment: Okay my bad, but this answer was flagged as low-quality, so please provide an explanation of how this code solves OP's problem.